# Tensorflow app freezes in docker container

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I have a tensorflow app that runs fine in ubuntu 16.04 but when I attempt to run it in the tensorflow/tensorflow docker image w/ nvidia-docker, it gets to this point and then freezes:

```
2017-07-12 22:06:10.917255: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow 
library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are 
available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-12 22:06:10.917289: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow 
library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are 
available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-12 22:06:11.023765: I 
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:901] successful 
NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be 
at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2017-07-12 22:06:11.024133: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:887] Found device 0 
with properties: 
name: Quadro M4000
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.7725
pciBusID 0000:00:05.0
Total memory: 7.93GiB
Free memory: 7.87GiB
2017-07-12 22:06:11.024159: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:908] DMA: 0 
2017-07-12 22:06:11.024168: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 0:   Y 
2017-07-12 22:06:11.024190: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977] Creating 
TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Quadro M4000, pci 
bus id: 0000:00:05.0)
```

Since it's not outputting an error message, I don't know where to start; any suggestions for something I might be missing or steps to troubleshoot this further?

I verified that my nvidia-docker installation is functioning correctly.

Comment: Can you attach a gdb and send a C stack trace? This is really weird...

Comment: @AlexandrePassos I've gotten a little further with this: my Dockerfile entrypoint is setup like this:
`ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "-m", "worker", "--data-dir", "/usr/src/app/data"]`
When I saw no output from my application, I assumed it hadn't started, but then realized it is running, as I can interact w/ it at it's defined port but docker logs isn't picking up any stdout from it. What's stranger is if I manually go into the container and launch the above command, I can see the output. Never seen anything like this before, what do you make of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the application was running, it just appeared to have frozen because output from python apps running in docker containers tends to get stuck in the buffer and never show up in the docker logs. To fix the problem I passed `-u` to python - I can see my application's output in docker logs now and all is well.